# How to create exportable images of tables?

Tags: python, uml

I've made a script that lets me extract class names, attributes, and methods to from a python file and return 3 lists: 1 with the class names, 1 with all the attributes and 1 with all the methods and I want to make a table like this out of them:

[image: UML Table]

Obviously I don't want to put images in it and I will like to export it as a .png or .jpg. Is there a library I can use to make this?

Comment: This is off-topic and likely will get closed.

Comment: You can get the Python 3 version of PIL (the Python Imaging Library), known as Pillow, from [here](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at the PIL (or Pillow) library, it is a library for image manipulations.
You can easily create an image (png or jpg), and draw on it / add text on it...

Maybe have a closer look to `PIL.ImageDraw.Draw.text` and `PIL.ImageDraw.Draw.rectangle`.

Hope it will be usefull for you.